# chaining grep commands to return values from different lines

Tags: search, logging, grep, command-line-interface

I have a large log file where I am currently running two commands. I search the log group and then make a filtered file where I return the following 3 lines after a match:

```
cat testFile.log |grep 'Text I am looking for' -A 3 > filter.txt
```

Then once I have my filtered file, I scan through that file to create myself a final file of the values I want:

```
cat filter.txt | grep -E 'Data\w{7}' -o > final.txt
```

My aim is to do this in one line if possible so I can wrap a bunch of these checks together in a script so I can jump in and search x,y,z and then I get a set of finalised files at the end for each one.

Comment: why don't you pipe that? `grep 'Text...' -A3 testFile.log | grep -oE 'Data...' > final.txt`

Comment: ah brilliant thankyou very much :) want to throw that into an answer for me to accept :) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make use of pipes. That is, the UNIX core way of thinking in which small pieces are grouped together to create a beautiful tool.

In this case you have to orders:

```
grep 'Text I am looking for' -A 3 testFile.log > filter.txt  # 1
grep -E 'Data\w{7}' -o  filter.txt > final.txt               # 2
```

(Note I removed the `cat file | grep '...'` since it is the same as saying `grep '...' file`)

Since the output of #1 is to feed #2, just use pipes:

```
grep -A 3 'Text I am looking for' testFile.log | grep -Eo 'Data\w{7}' > final.txt
```

This way you prevent the use of an unnecessary intermediate file.